# Not getting (SELECT) all the results using where in MySql Database

Tags: mysql, select, where-clause, mysql-workbench

Last night I had a question to make sure that I had formatted my php correctly to ensure I was able to test out the query. Today while working in mysql workbench I found that I was unable to get all the results I wanted. I have currently 15 rows in my "contact" table but when I run the following code, only 8 come through. Mind you I AM using multiple tables but some of these tables have more than one row per contact and some have no rows for some and multiple for others in the same table.

```
 SELECT 
`Contact`.`firstName`,
`Contact`.`lastName`,
`ssn`.`ssn`,
`Contact`.`country`,
`Allergies`.`allergy`,
`Allergies`.`allergyType`,
`Allergies_Contact`.`allergyNotes`,
`CurrentPrescriptions`.`prescriptionName`,
`CurrentPrescriptions`.`prescribedDate`,
`BloodType`.`bloodType`
FROM
`mher`.`Contact`,
`mher`.`Allergies_Contact`,
`mher`.`Allergies`,
`mher`.`ssn`,
`mher`.`CurrentPrescriptions`,
`mher`.`BloodType`
WHERE
`Contact`.`contactKey` = `Allergies_Contact`.`contactKey`
    AND `Allergies`.`allergiesKey` = `Allergies_Contact`.`allergiesKey`
    AND `ssn`.`contactKey` = `Contact`.`contactKey`
    AND `CurrentPrescriptions`.`contactKey` = `Contact`.`contactKey`
    AND `BloodType`.`contactKey` = `Contact`.`contactKey`;
```

[image]

Comment: Is there any chance we can see your table structure?

Comment: @Lazenbyt-mherPresident he is asking why you are surrounding each column with these characters: ` ` ````

Comment: @JonH Those are the default MySQL escape characters, most databases use `[]`, mysql uses `\`\``

Comment: scragar - That's fine I am just letting him know what Avinash was asking as he mentioned the comment made no sense.

Comment: added the db structure to main

Comment: After re-reading your question it sounds like you want entries where there are no results for some tables, is that correct, and if so which tables?

Comment: This is correct, the Allergy tables (Allergies and Allergy_Contact) and the prescription table

Comment: ssn's a separate table? How does that work? Equally, blood type - a separate table implies that a user can have more than one type. Is this to allow for chimeras?

Comment: Oh, chimeras are more common than I realized.

Comment: No, the separate table is part of a multi step security measure for the data specifically in THAT table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you give this a go, I've made it a left join on the tables you don't need entries for:

```
  SELECT 
     `Contact`.`firstName`,
     `Contact`.`lastName`,
     `ssn`.`ssn`,
     `Contact`.`country`,
     `Allergies`.`allergy`,
     `Allergies`.`allergyType`,
     `Allergies_Contact`.`allergyNotes`,
     `CurrentPrescriptions`.`prescriptionName`,
     `CurrentPrescriptions`.`prescribedDate`,
     `BloodType`.`bloodType`
  FROM
     `mher`.`Contact`
     INNER JOIN `mher`.`ssn`
        ON `ssn`.`contactKey` = `Contact`.`contactKey`
     INNER JOIN `mher`.`BloodType`
        ON `BloodType`.`contactKey` = `Contact`.`contactKey`
     LEFT JOIN `mher`.`Allergies_Contact`
        ON `Contact`.`contactKey` = `Allergies_Contact`.`contactKey`
     LEFT JOIN `mher`.`Allergies`
        ON `Allergies`.`allergiesKey` = `Allergies_Contact`.`allergiesKey`
     LEFT JOIN `mher`.`CurrentPrescriptions`
        ON `CurrentPrescriptions`.`contactKey` = `Contact`.`contactKey`
  ;
```

Comment: that worked, can you explain why solution wasn't working and why yours did

Comment: Certainly, you were doing what is called a qualified cross join, which is exactly the same as the explicit joins I've replaced it with above, with one big exception, using a `LEFT JOIN` says if the matching row doesn't exist join me to an all null row instead(where an `INNER JOIN` or `WHERE` condition would discard the row).

Comment: This makes sense, I knew that there was something else missing from my arguments, but reading the documentation for mysql queries I was having a hard time figuring out how to bring in the null rows

Answer (score 0):

or - to my mind/eye, more readable...

```
SELECT c.firstName
     , c.lastName
     , ssn.ssn
     , c.country
     , a.allergy
     , a.allergyType,
     , ac.allergyNotes
     , pc.prescriptionName
     , pc.prescribedDate
     , bc.bloodType
  FROM Contact c
  LEFT
  JOIN Allergies_Contact ac
    ON ac.contactKey = c.contactKey 
  LEFT
  JOIN Allergies a
    ON a.allergiesKey = ac.allergiesKey
  JOIN ssn
    ON ssn.contactKey = c.contactKey
  LEFT
  JOIN CurrentPrescriptions
    ON pc.contactKey = c.contactKey
  JOIN BloodType
   AND bc.contactKey = c.contactKey;
```